# using array in JPQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

How can I use an array list in JPQL query? I want something like this:
I am passing this

```
private static final String[] MASKS = {"30109", "30111"};
```

into

```
public List<Account> findAccount(String[] Masks){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("from AccountTable a where SUBSTRING(a.Account,1,5) in :Masks ");
Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), AccountTable.class)
                .setParameter("Masks",Masks);
}
```

currently, error is

```
Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reading [this site](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/collection#NOT_IN_) it seems that is possible, but your array must be a `Collection`, maybe something like this:

```
public List<Account> findAccount(String[] Masks){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("from AccountTable a where SUBSTRING(a.Account,1,5) in :Masks ");
    Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), AccountTable.class)
                .setParameter("Masks", Arrays.asList(MASKS));
}
```

Should help you.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks